# Difference between script src and code inside script in asp.net mvc 3 razor partial view executing jquery.ajax

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-3, jquery-plugins

asp.net mvc 3 with razor
I have a script inside a partial view

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function MYFunction()
{
...
</script>
```

It's working fine

If I move the code inside a .js file and try to load the script with

```
<script src="path to my script file" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

The script doesn't execute some code, a jquery.ajax, the rest of the code is executed (I'm debugging inside visual studio)

Any suggestion?

Comment: Should something to be done after DOM is finished loading? (ie. `$(document).ready(...)`)

Comment: Is the script being called and ran before jQuery is loaded?

Comment: the jquery references are in the _layout.cshtml (master page) and the <script src=....> is in a partial view, and the same script that work inside the partial view doesn't work if I move it to a js file and reference with <script src= ...>

Comment: Maybe supply the actual javascript as well as part of the question - it could be something there...

Comment: Can you please explain what was the error? it looks like you accepted an answer with your exact code...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try following:

> <script type="text/javascript" src="path to my script file">

Comment: Is it possible that the file is not being accessed by the browser? Try to confirm it with sth like Firebug. It may happen that the JS file is not accessible

Comment: Yes, my mistake, I was using razor for the path with an error

Answer (score 2):

My guess is that you use the '@' symbol and some c# code inside the javascript function and it doesn't work inside js file only in cshtml - razor file.
Am I right?

Answer (score 0):

Ensure your scripts are loading in the proper order. Meaning, if your script uses JQuery then you will have to have the  tag loading JQuery BEFORE your script's  tag.

Comment: I will check the html page and will tell you, but I'm pretty sure that is loading in the proper order. The only difference between the working code and the code that doesn't work is load the script from a js file